# how to prevent html injection in C++ server?

Tags: c++, serversocket, urlconnection

I am working in client-server application in which client is written in java and server in C++.
We detect a HTML injection vulnerability as we give in URL the HTML code along with the valid URL as :https:\[ip of server]:[port no]\?, Our application processes this url and return some garbage.

Now i am in process of finding how URL in handled first time means where we send a reply first time to the request https:\[ip of server]:[port no].

As i know C++ does not have Socket or URLConnection library in-built, i saw there is SOCKET.CPP file in our projcet that is copyright to BMC software and this file has methods read,write,close,enableBlocking,disableBlocking,initializeInterface,uninitializeInterface.

I know java but have a very little knowledge in C++. Could anyone please guide to find the where we send response to the above mentioned URL. I need a approach to find that place in this huge project. Thanks in advance...

Comment: sorry, my crystal ball is laying at home. Cant find the source code spot without the source-code (or without my crystal ball).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had written a c++ server to process client requests.

I would parse the request url after I get the request, and check whether the request url is valid, for example, the request is a invalid one if it does not start with "/temp".

afterwards I used nginx to stop these invalid request(you could set the valid request url format in the nginx.conf) before sending to the c++ server, and it worked well.

maybe you could try nginx.